# System events script sometimes works, sometimes doesn't

Tags: macos, applescript, google-chrome

This is a part of a bigger script that I isolated and have an issue with:

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
delay 2
tell application "System Events"
    click ¬
        pop up button "Multi Layout Manager" of ¬
        toolbar 1 of group 1 of window 1 of ¬
        application process "Chrome"
    delay 0.2
    repeat 3 times
        key code 48 -- # tab key
        delay 0.2
    end repeat
    key code 36 -- # enter key
end tell
```

It automatically clicks on a Chrome extension (Multi Layout Manager) and selects a saved template.

Sometimes it works like a charm, then other times it just doesn't.
The error I get is this:

```
error "System Events got an error: Can’t get pop up button \"Multi Layout Manager\" of toolbar 1 of group 1 of window 1 of application process \"Chrome\"." number -1728 from pop up button "Multi Layout Manager" of toolbar 1 of group 1 of window 1 of application process "Chrome"
```

I can't figure out what's wrong here. Some help would be great.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

I could not test this following code because I do not have `pop up button "Multi Layout Manager"`, but I think this should achieve what you are looking for.

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
delay 2
tell application "System Events"
    set frontmost of application process "Google Chrome" to true
    repeat until application process "Google Chrome" is frontmost
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    tell application process "Google Chrome"
        repeat until pop up button "Multi Layout Manager" of toolbar 1 of group 1 of window 1 exists
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
        click pop up button "Multi Layout Manager" of toolbar 1 of group 1 of window 1
        delay 0.2
        repeat 3 times
            key code 48 -- # tab key
            delay 0.2
        end repeat
        key code 36 -- # enter key
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Stuck on "Running". It seems to me that it gets in a loop here:
`
repeat until pop up button "Multi Layout Manager" of toolbar 1 of group 1 of window 1 exists
`
and it can't get out. Any clue why?